# Samsung S9: Reports rounded RggbChannelVector values

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile, android-camera2, samsung-galaxy

I'm attempting to extract the white balance parameters from the auto white balance algorithm in the S9.  On every other device I've tested, it gives meaningful parameters back (the numbers have a floating point precision of like 6 digits and are constantly changing) but the S9 appears to round it's result parameters to the nearest whole number which ends up being giving some very poor results in terms of color balance.  Here's the code I am using to do this:

```
if (result.get(CaptureResult.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS) != null) {
    channelVector = result.get(CaptureResult.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS);
}
```

Anybody else run into this issue and if so... any solutions to it out there???

Answer (score 0):

Consider working with custom [Samsung Camera API](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera). These days, it is based on **camera2**.

Specifically, they provide their [COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS](https://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/camera/com/samsung/android/sdk/camera/SCaptureResult.html#COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS). They also [explain](https://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/camera/com/samsung/android/sdk/camera/SCaptureResult.html#COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE) that

> … the camera device may do additional processing but android.colorCorrection.gains and android.colorCorrection.transform will still be provided by the camera device (in the results) and be ***roughly*** correct.

(the emphasis is mine)